# Split column and keep split columns inside dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a Badge column into separate columns while also maintaining the order of the dataframe. For example, Steph should have 2 additional columns splitting his 2 badges separated by the | character.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Player': ['Steph', 'LeBron', 'Giannis'],
        'Badge': ['200 3PT Sniper | 210 Rim Finisher', '210 Rim Finisher | 205 Deadeye Passer | 215 Point Forward', '220 2Way Playmaker | 210 Rim Finisher']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

End result should be

```
    Player             Badge_1             Badge_2            Badge_3
0    Steph      200 3PT Sniper    210 Rim Finisher                   
1   LeBron    210 Rim Finisher  205 Deadeye Passer  215 Point Forward
2  Giannis  220 2Way Playmaker    210 Rim Finisher
```

Comment: Avoid including screenshots of images if possible, better to describe what your ideal result should be. It's also generally better to share what you have already tried to solve the problem so that fellow users can guide you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
out = (df.drop(columns='Badge')
         .join(df['Badge'].str.split(r'\s*\|\s*', expand=True)
                 .rename(columns=lambda c: f'Badge_{c+1}')
                 .fillna(''))
      )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    Player             Badge_1             Badge_2            Badge_3
0    Steph      200 3PT Sniper    210 Rim Finisher                   
1   LeBron    210 Rim Finisher  205 Deadeye Passer  215 Point Forward
2  Giannis  220 2Way Playmaker    210 Rim Finisher
```